# « Être intéressé(e) de/par/à qqch » et « qqch m'intéresse »

Tags: expressions, prépositions

> Je suis intéressé(e) par votre appartement/de votre appartement/à votre appartement.
>
> Je ne suis pas intéressé(e) par votre appartement/de votre appartement/à votre appartement.
>
> Votre appartement (ne) m'intéresse (pas).

La tournure *Être intéressé(e)* doit-elle être suivie par *de*, *par* ou *à* dans ce contexte ? Quelles tournures sont les plus courantes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seulement « par » est une possibilité. 
La tournure utilisant « par » est alors forcément la plus courante des trois.

La tournure « Votre appartement (ne) m'intéresse (pas). » est utilisable de la même façon, pour dire que l'on trouve ou non un appartement convenable en tant qu achat possible ou  possible prise en  location. Il y a des façons moins abruptes de dire ces choses-là, cependant ; voici une option dans le sens de ne pas s'exposer au  risque de blesser les agents immobiliers ou les propriétaires.

- Votre appartement ne correspond pas exactement à mes besoins.
- Votre appartement correspond  à mes besoins.

Cela ne signifie pas que les tournures que vous proposez soient inutilisables, elles restent polies si le ton duquel elles sont prononcées est correct, mais elles sont moins souples.

Comment: Merci. Votre appartement (ne) m'intéresse (pas) n'est-elle pas correcte/courante ? Ne peut-on pas utiliser *à* ?

Comment: @Dimitris Désolé, je n'ai pas fait assez attention. Je complète ma réponse.

Answer (score 3):

*être intéressé par* est le seul juste des trois.  Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse dire *être intéressé* *de* quel que soit le contexte.  Par contre, on peut dire *s'intéresser à* :

- Je m'intéresse à votre appartement.

On peut également dire dans un contexte financier :

- Je suis intéressé aux bénéfices de l'entreprise.

Ce qui veut dire :

- I get a share of the company's profits

Comment: Merci. La tournure "Votre appartement (ne) m'intéresse (pas)." est-elle correcte/courante ? Si elle correcte, existe-t-il des différences avec "Je suis intéressé par votre appartement" ? De plus "Je m'intéresse à votre appartement" est équivalente avec la tournure avec par ?

Comment: Si c'est dans un contexte d'achat d'appartement, je dirais : "votre appartement m'intéresse" ou "je suis intéressé par votre appartement", sous-entendu, je voudrais en savoir plus, le visiter…

Comment: La tournure avec "par" est juste la forme passive de la première: A intéresse B <=> B est intéressé par A.